# Monk - Why do my updates only work sometimes?

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, set, monk

I am building a web application using the MEVN Stack. I am using the npm package 'Monk' to communicate with MongoDB.

I have a route that inserts a new document into a collection, and when it gets called it is also supposed to update a document in another collection. However, this only works occasionally and often times it just doesn't.

Here is my calling code

```
async function updateConccurentdays(id) {
    try {
        const result = await exercises.findOne({
            client_id: id
        }, {
            sort: {
                date: -1
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("error in find " + error.message)
        });
        const rating = result.exercises[0].rating
        await clients.update(
            {id: id},
            {$set :{lastRating: rating}})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error in update " + error.message)
    }
}
```

The issue is in my clients.update(), sometimes it works and sometimes I get the following:
  monk:query update: {"n":1,"nModified":0,"ok":1}

and it doesn't update the document.

Comment: Does the `id` already exist in the clients collection?  If no, you'll need to upsert.

Comment: Hi @Joe, yes it does exists.